# Calling JavaScript function from PHP echo within a radio button

Tags: php, javascript, radio-button

I have a series of radio buttons, which onClick will either reveal or hide a Div:

**Reveal the Div:**

```
<input type="radio" name="con[4]" value="1" onclick="toggleLayer4(this.checked);" id="con4" />
```

**Hide the Div:**

```
<input type="radio" name="con[4]" value="0" onclick="toggleLayer4(!this.checked);" checked="checked" id="con4" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function toggleLayer4(val)
        {
            if(val == '1' || val === true)
            {
                document.getElementById('con4').checked = true;
                document.getElementById('con4PSTN').style.display = 'block';
            }
            else if(val == '0' || val === false)
            {
                document.getElementById('con4').checked = false;
                document.getElementById('con4PSTN').style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
```

Now the problem, when the pag is recalled, I can get the radio button checked like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="con[4]" value="1" onclick="toggleLayer4(this.checked);" <? if ($conn_count[3] == 1){echo "checked=\"checked\"";}?> id="con4" />
```

But I need a away of calling the JavaScript function to reveal the div if the radio button is checked, I have tried to echo `toggleLayer4(this.checked);` within the PHP if statement inside  tags, however this just seems to reurn the text in the html??

There must be a way, not really versed in JS.

Cheers,
B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a plain unobtrusive javascript for you which will save you some work - please notice there are no event handlers on the radios anymore.

I gave them unique IDs which is mandatory.

If you ever need to use jQuery for other stuff, this script can be a little more elegant.

I assume

```
<input type="radio" name="con[1]" value="1" id="con1_1" />
<input type="radio" name="con[1]" value="0" id="con1_0" />
<input type="radio" name="con[2]" value="1" id="con2_1" />
<input type="radio" name="con[2]" value="0" id="con2_0" />
<input type="radio" name="con[3]" value="1" id="con3_1" />
<input type="radio" name="con[3]" value="0" id="con3_0" />
<input type="radio" name="con[4]" value="1" id="con4_1" />
<input type="radio" name="con[4]" value="0" id="con4_0" />
```

and matching object to have conxPSTN where **x** is the number in the con[**x**]

```
window.onload=function() {
  var conLength = <?php echo count($con); ?>;
  for (var i=1;i<=conLength;i++) {
    var cons = document.getElementsByName("con["+i+"]");
    for (var j=0;j<cons.length;j++) {
      cons[j].onclick=function() {
        var id = this.id.split("_")[0];
        document.getElementById(id+"PSTN").style.display = (this.value==1)?"block":"none"
      }
      if (cons[j].checked) cons[j].click();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I like your solution very much, Im having trouble though, as even if the button is maually checked, the corresponding Div is not revealed, here is the code for the div that needs revealing / hiding:

<div class="hide" id="con1PSTNdiv">
  PSTN line?<br />
   <label>
    <input type="radio" name="conPSTN[1]" value="1" <? if ($conn_count[0] == 2){echo 'checked="checked"';}?> id="con1PSTN" />
    Yes</label>
  <br />
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="conPSTN[1]" value="0" <? if ($conn_count[0] != 2){echo 'checked="checked"';}?> id="con1PSTN" />
    No</label> 
  </div>

Comment: Oh and you assumed correct! Also, where you have echoed $con, there is no $con, there will always be 10 Divs to reveal...

Comment: +1 though it would be better if you not use `cons[j].onclick`. Use `addEventListener`.

Comment: @jrh Nah, then I need to attachEvent too - onclick works for all browsers I know.

Answer (score 0):

If you are echoing from php then you should do like

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>toggleLayer4(this.checked);</script>";
```

But you cant use `this` in there. You need to get the value of the radio button manually n pass it

**EDIT**

This is the case when you want to call the function explicitly in some part of the code and when the php code is **not** with the `<script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <input type="radio" name="con[4]" value="0" onclick="toggleLayer4(0);" checked="checked" id="con4" />


   <input type="radio" name="con[4]" value="1" onclick="toggleLayer4(1);" checked="checked" id="con4" />
 function toggleLayer4(val)
    {
    if(val){
     document.getElementById('con4PSTN').style.display = 'block';}
    else{
     document.getElementById('con4PSTN').style.display = 'none';
    }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot have both checked and you do not check the checked value onload in your code.